# Rails foreign key to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that contains workorders. I'm going to be loading workorders from another system.  That system uses a single table for parent and child workorders.

I added a field to the workorders table called parent_id

Is this the right coding in the Workorder model?

```
 class ParentWorkorder
   belongs_to :parent, class_name => "Workorder"
   belongs_to :child, class_name =>  "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
 end
```

Or would you advise against doing this - and instead create a child workorder table?  I think that might make it harder to integrate with the other system.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget the `:` before `class_name`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single table with Rails as well, and for that matter with a single model. I don't see why you'd need to complicate your app with an additional `ParentWorkorder` model like you have done. I would instead do the following:

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Workorder", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

I'm pretty sure this will give you the functionality that you want.

Comment: I take it `t.references :workorder` in a migration file will then create a column called `parent_id`?

Answer (score 2):

I would put the child as a has_one or has_many(if a parent can have more than one). But yes, this works well.

You may want to get into the habit of using symbols instead of strings where possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input -- but, please give me an example of using a symbol instead of a string.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Instead of "WorkOrder" you can do :work_order, instead of "parent_id" you can do :parent_id

Symbols are like strings but are immutable, which takes fewer resources.
http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm